# Neo4j shortestPath with highest aggregated relationship propertie

Tags: neo4j, max, cypher, shortest-path

I want to find the shortest path between two nodes. The path itself is not the problem... The bigger problem is, that I´ll want to return the path, where the aggregated relationship property on the path is highest.

For better understanding, here´s what I want:

This is my query

```
MATCH
  (startNode:Person {id:"887111"}),
  (endNode:Person {id:"789321"}),
  paths = allShortestPaths((startNode)-[r:KNOWS *..20]-(endNode))
RETURN paths
```

[image: Query result]

In this example I´ll want to have the path from Elissa (id: 887111) to Kasey (id: 789321) where the aggregated count ON the relationship is MAX. 
I´ve also had a look at 'shortestPath', which only gives me one path. The other way is to call the 'dijkstra'-algo, with this I´ll get only the path with the lowest 'cost' (and not the highest). 
So in my example the only path which should shown up is *Elissa->Travon->Kasey*

I´d think, the problem isn´t that complex, but at the moment I´m gettin stucked with this..

Thanks so far in advance.

---

### UPDATE

after calling the suggested query

```
MATCH  (startNode:Person {id:"789321"}), (endNode:Person {id:"887111"}) 
CALL apoc.algo.dijkstra(startNode, endNode, 'KNOWS', '_duration') YIELD path, weight 
RETURN path, -weight AS weight
```

my result is the following

[image: updated result]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[UPDATED]

I present 2 answers, depending one what you are trying to do.

#### 1. Finding path with max total weight

To find the path with max total weight, you  can feed to the Dijkstra algorithm the *negation* of the original weight properties. The resulting "lowest" total weight will be a negative value that, when negated, will actually be the highest total weight (based on the original weight properties).

There is an APOC procedure, [apoc.algo.dijkstra](https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures/#_graph_algorithms_work_in_progress) that implements the Dijkstra algorithm, but it does not allow you to use the negative value of the specified weight property. So, to use that procedure, you would need to add a new property to each `KNOWS` relationship with the appropriate negative value. For example, to add the negative weights to existing relationships (assuming `w` is the original weight property, and `_w` will contain the corresponding negative value):

```
MATCH ()-[k:KNOWS]->()
SET k._w = -k.w;
```

Once you have the negative weights, the following should give you the path with the max weight:

```
MATCH (startNode:Person {id:"887111"}), (endNode:Person {id:"789321"})
CALL apoc.algo.dijkstra(startNode, endNode, 'KNOWS', '_w') YIELD path, weight
RETURN path, -weight AS weight;
```

#### 2. Choosing from the shortest paths the one with maximum total weight

```
MATCH
  (startNode:Person {id:"887111"}),
  (endNode:Person {id:"789321"}),
  path = allShortestPaths((startNode)-[:KNOWS *..20]-(endNode))
RETURN path, REDUCE(s = 0, r IN RELATIONSHIPS(path) | s + r.duration) AS weight
ORDER BY weight DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

Comment: ok.. sound´s pretty good BUT I´ve tested it and I was wondered, that a completely other path is proposed... The dijkstra algorithm gives me another way for Elissa->Kasey, but with a way higher count (see update in original post)

Comment: The `apoc.algo.dijkstra` procedure supports undirected relationship patterns (without the ">" or "<" characters) as well, which is what I used in my answer.

Comment: you´re right... Nevertheless I´ve updated my original answer & post, cause there´s still an error respectively a new error.

Comment: Depending on your version of the neo4j browser, you may have an Auto-Complete switch on the bottom right corner of the result pane. Turn that off so that it doesn't visualize things that are not actually in your Cypher results. Or, use the `Table`, `Text`, or `Code` tabs to see the actual results.

Comment: Also, based on the data provided, I cannot reproduce your issue. You may need to upgrade to a more recent version of neo4j and the apoc plugin.

Comment: I think the problem is not Neo4J.. I run on version 3.1.3 (with apoc 3.1.3.7). 
Well.. Do you think that there´s no possibility to set a filter on my shortest paths, where I can exclude the path with the lowest _duration_-count, so that only the shortest path with the highest _duration_-count is shown up?

Comment: Can you explain what the problem is, if it is not with neo4j?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/144961/discussion-between-andy-and-cybersam).